# How to print method?

Tags: java

How can I output methodA to my main method?

```
public class A{
    public static void methodA(int c){
        int b = 7;
        System.out.println("output: " + b + " and " + c);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(methodA()); // the error that I recieve is cannot be applied to ()
        System.out.println(c); // the error that I receive is Expression expected
        System.out.println(methodA); // the error that I recieve is Expression expected
    }
}
```

My code is a lot more complicated, but this is the outline of what I need help with. How can I print the information that is in methodA to the main method?

The error that I've been receving is

Comment: You need to pass argument to methodA like this `System.out.println(methodA(1));`

Comment: Return the string from methodA and print that value in the main

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Give an example what exactly you want to print.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you need to print a lot of information to understand the flow of your application, you should look into logging. I would recommend nlog or log4net, which are both great options for logging on the machine where your code is running.

If you need centralized logging, then look into Serilog and Elastichsearch.

What I think you are asking Ahmed, is how to print arguments passed to methodA, which is fairly simple.

```
public class A
{
    public static void methodA(int c)
    {
       int b = 7;
       System.out.println("output: " + b + " and " + c);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       int c = 12;
       methodA(12);
       System.out.println(c); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your method require one integer variable as an argument. You have to pass one integer as an argument to execute `methodA` method. For example:

```
public class A{
    public static void methodA(int c){
       int b = 7;
       System.out.println("output: " + b + " and " + c);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int integerVariable = 5;
        methodA(integerVariable); 
    }
 }
```

> Note: As given method is of void type , you can not write
>   `System.out.println(methodA(integerVariable))` inside main method.